# Objective-C: How to extract part of a String (e.g. start with '#')

Tags: objective-c, ios, hash, nsstring, substring

I have a string as shown below,

```
NSString * aString = @"This is the #substring1 and #subString2 I want";
```

How can I select only the text starting with '#' (and ends with a space), in this case 'subString1' and 'subString2'?

Note: Question was edited for clarity

Comment: How do you know where the substrings end?

Comment: According to the question, I think he means everything up until a space.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can do this using an [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to split the string up. This code will loop through a string and fill an array with substrings.

```
NSString * aString = @"This is the #substring1 and #subString2 I want";
NSMutableArray *substrings = [NSMutableArray new];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:aString];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"#" intoString:nil]; // Scan all characters before #
while(![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    NSString *substring = nil;
    [scanner scanString:@"#" intoString:nil]; // Scan the # character
    if([scanner scanUpToString:@" " intoString:&substring]) {
        // If the space immediately followed the #, this will be skipped
        [substrings addObject:substring];
    }
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"#" intoString:nil]; // Scan all characters before next #
}
// do something with substrings
[substrings release];
```

Here is how the code works:

1. Scan up to a #. If it isn't found, the scanner will be at the end of the string.
2. If the scanner is at the end of the string, we are done.
3. Scan the # character so that it isn't in the output.
4. Scan up to a space, with the characters that are scanned stored in `substring`. If either the # was the last character, or was immediately followed by a space, the method will return NO. Otherwise it will return YES.
5. If characters were scanned (the method returned YES), add `substring` to the `substrings` array.
6. GOTO 1

Answer (score 35):

```
[aString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(13, 10)]
```

would give you substring1

You can calculate the range using:

```
NSRange startRange = [aString rangeOfString:@"#"];
NSRange endRange = [original rangeOfString:@"1"];

NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(startRange.location , endRange.location);
[aString substringWithRange:searchRange]
```

would give you substring1

Read more:
[Position of a character in a NSString or NSMutableString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379997/position-of-a-character-in-a-nsstring-or-nsmutablestring)

and

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/nsrange-and-nsstring-objects.html

Comment: substring1 was just an example. Hard coding to look for "1" is just bad. This is not a right solution if you don't know what the string is after #. Also this doesn't answer OP question to look for every occurrence of string after #. What about substring2?

Answer (score 11):

Pretty simple, easy to understand version avoiding `NSRange` stuff:

```
NSArray * words = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]; 
NSMutableArray * mutableWords = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString * word in words){
    if ([word length] > 1 && [word characterAtIndex:0] == '#'){
        NSString * editedWord = [word substringFromIndex:1];
        [mutableWords addObject:editedWord];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the best answer because it is the most simple and effective!

Comment: Gives me a comparing warning.  Had to make a string compare=@"#" and then had to use [word characterAtIndex:0] == [compare characterAtIndex:0].

Comment: Yes it is,Pretty simple +1

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are looking to find the first string that starts with a pound, and ends with a space, this might work.  I don't have XCode in front of me, so forgive me if there's a syntax error or length off by 1 somewhere:

```
-(NSString *)StartsWithPound:(NSString *)str {
    NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:@"#"];
    if(range.length) {
        NSRange rangeend = [str rangeOfString:@" " options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(range.location,[str length] - range.location - 1)];
        if(rangeend.length) {
            return [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(range.location,rangeend.location - range.location)];
        }
        else
        {
            return [str substringFromIndex:range.location];
        }
    }
    else {
        return @"";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another simple solution:

```
NSRange hashtag = [aString rangeOfString:@"#"];
NSRange word = [[aString substringFromIndex:hashtag.location] rangeOfString:@" "];
NSString *hashtagWord = [aString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(hashtag.location, word.location)];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'd do:

```
NSString *givenStringWithWhatYouNeed = @"What you want to look through";
NSArray *listOfWords = [givenStringWithWhatYouNeed componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
for (NSString *word in listOfWords) {
    if ([[word substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)]isEqualToString:@"#"]) {
        NSString *whatYouWant = [[word componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"]lastObject];
    }
}
```

Then you can do what you need with the `whatYouWant` instances. If you want to know which string it is (if it's the substring 1 or 2), check the index of of `word` string in the `listOfWords` array.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A general and simple code to select all the words starting with "#" in a NSString is:

```
NSString * aString = @"This is the #substring1 and #subString2 ...";
NSMutableArray *selection=@[].mutableCopy;
while ([aString rangeOfString:@"#"].location != NSNotFound)
{
    aString = [aString substringFromIndex:[aString rangeOfString:@"#"].location +1];
    NSString *item=([aString rangeOfString:@" "].location != NSNotFound)?[aString substringToIndex:[aString rangeOfString:@" "].location]:aString;
    [selection addObject:item];
}
```

if you still need the original string you can do a copy.
The inline conditional is used in case your selected item is the last word