# Separate part of string from whole string

Tags: iphone, string, ipad, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C: How to extract part of a String (e.g. start with '#')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825834/objective-c-how-to-extract-part-of-a-string-e-g-start-with)

I want to divide string in to few parts. My string is:

```
NSString * myString = @"Multiply top and bottom to get < mathtype x3y2z3 over x3yz2 >,now cancel down the powers of < i >x, y, z< /i >.If you prefer, you can cancel down before you start multiplying.";
```

I need three parts from this.
1. Multiply top and bottom to get 
2. < mathtype x3y2z3 over x3yz2 > 
3. ,now cancel down the powers of < i >x, y, z< /i >.If you prefer, you can cancel down before you start multiplying.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the above fails you could always convert it to an array of characters and loop through it.

```
- (const char *)cStringUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

there are more details in the [NSString Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)