# iOS finding string within a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, string, nsstring

Hello everyone I am trying find a string inside a string
lets say I have a string:

> word1/word2/word3

I want to find the word from the end of the string to the last "/"
so what I will get from that string is:

> Word3

How do I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Do these strings represent file paths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method

```
NSString *originalString = @"word1/word2/word3";
NSArray *separatedArray = [originalString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSString *lastObject = [separatedArray lastObject]; //word3
```

Answer (score 3):

once check this one By using this one you'l get last pathcomponent values,

```
NSString* theFileName = @"how /are / you ";
    NSString *str1=[theFileName lastPathComponent];
    NSLog(@"%@",str1);
```

By using lastPathComponent you'l get the last path component directly no need to take array for separate the string.

Comment: @user1014334:no need to take array use NSString class methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *string = @"word1/word2/word3"
NSArray *arr = [string componentsSeperatedByString:@"/"];
NSSting *str = [arr lastObject];
```

Comment: What I meant is that the "Words" can be anything.
and not only "word 1 word 2 word 3" sorry for not explaining well...

Answer (score 2):

you must use NSScanner class to split substring.

check this.

[Objective C: How to extract part of a String (e.g. start with '#')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825834/objective-c-how-to-extract-part-of-a-string-e-g-start-with)

Answer (score 2):

You can find it also with this way:

```
NSMutableString *string=[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"word1/word2/word3"];
NSRange range=[string rangeOfString:@"/" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSString *subString=[string substringFromIndex:range.location+1];
```

Answer (score 1):

[NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [NSString rangeOfString:options:range:locale:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3aoptions%3arange%3alocale%3a) (with options to search backwards).

The answer really depends on exactly what the input string will contain (how consistent it is).