# NSString get substring separed by 2 defined strings

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have some `NSString` object, for example:

```
NSString *inputString1 = @"Name is \"Mark\"";
NSString *inputString2 = @"Name is \"Joe\"";
```

I need to extract `Mark` and `Joe` values substrings from input.

Are there any solutions?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: If the prefix is always `"Name is \""`, you can use `[inputString1 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(9, inputString1.length-10)]`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825834/objective-c-how-to-extract-part-of-a-string-e-g-start-with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *firstName = 
[[inputString1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""] objectAtIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *name = [[inputString  componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] lastObject];
name = [name stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
```