# How to delete a substring from NSString from a specific position?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

I want to set UIWebView with htmlstring and I have problem with an image:
...

```
<img align="absBottom" alt="" height="350" src="http://www.xyz.com//files/userfiles/images/abc.jpg" vspace="10" width="625" />
```

...

I want to replace height and width to 200 and 320. 
I'm using

```
htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"width=\"" withString:@"width=\"320];
```

then I've got result :

```
<img align="absBottom" alt="" height="350" src="http://www.xyz.com//files/userfiles/images/abc.jpg" vspace="10" width="320625" />
```

How to delete the number after the width from htmlString or what is the right way to replace the width to 320px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `NSScanner`:

```
NSScanner *theScanner;
NSString *subStrng =nil;
theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:htmlString];
[theScanner scanUpToString:@"width" intoString:NULL] ;
[theScanner scanUpToString:@" " intoString:&subStrng] ;
htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", subStrng] withString::@"width=\"320\""];
NSLog("%@",subStrng);
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. But changes only the first image in html code.

Comment: Follow the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825834/objective-c-how-to-extract-part-of-a-string-e-g-start-with You'l need little modification.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"width=\"625" withString:@"width=\"320];
```

Comment: Then you should be using `NSRegularExpression`.