# Objective-C NSString for loop with characterAtIndex

Tags: objective-c, xcode, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through a NSString, character by character, but I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Do you have an idea how to do this right? I've been googling for hours now but can't figure it out.

Here is my code (.m):

```
self.textLength = [self.text length];

for (int position=0; position < self.textLength; position++) {

    NSLog(@"%@", [self.text characterAtIndex:position]);

    if ([[self.text characterAtIndex:position] isEqualToString:@"."]){
        NSLog(@"it's a .");
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you just trying to find the position of a particular character in a string? If yes, there's an easier solution

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Characters are not object. `characterAtIndex` returns `unichar`, which is actually an integer type `unsigned short`. You need to use `%C` instead of `%@` in `NSLog`. Also character is not a `NSString`, so you can't send it `isEqualToString`. You need to use `ch == '.'` to compare `ch` against `'.'`.

```
unichar ch = [self.text characterAtIndex:position];
NSLog(@"%C", ch);

if (ch == '.') {} // single quotes around dot, not double quotes
```

Note that, `'a'` is character, `"a"` is C string and `@"a"` is NSString. They all are different types.

When you are using `%@` with unichar `ch` in `NSLog`, it is trying to print an object from memory location `ch` which is invalid. Thus you are getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, as well as the great explanation!

Comment: Great, thanks! I was using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%hu"` which also caused an error.

Answer (score 4):

`characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar`, so you should use `NSLog(@"%C", ...)` instead of `@"%@"`.

You also cannot use `isEqualToString` for a `unichar`, just use `== '.'` is fine.

If you want to find the position of all '.'s, you can use `rangeOfString`. Refer to:

- [String Programming Guide: Searching, Comparing, and Sorting Strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000149-CJBBGBAI)
- [Position of a character in a NSString or NSMutableString](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2379997/1241690)

Answer (score 0):

`characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar`, which is declared as `typedef unsigned short unichar;` The format specifier you are using in your calls to `NSLog` are incorrect, you could just do `NSLog(@"%u",[self.text characterAtIndex:position]);` or `NSLog(@"%C",[self.text characterAtIndex:position]);` if you want the actual character to print out.

Also, as a result of unichar being defined the way that it is, it's not a string, so you cannot compare it to other strings. Try something like:

```
unichar textCharacter = '.';

if ([self.text characterAtPosition:position] == testCharacter) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the location of a character in a string you can use this:

```
NSUInteger position = [text rangeOfString:@"."].location;
```

if the character or text is not found you will get a NSNotFound:

```
if(position==NSNotFound)
    NSLog(@"text not found!");
```